How to connect input of information in wordpress and sending it using php to the VDS?
How to connect input of information in wordpress and sending via php on VPS (the site itself is on hosting)? With the second one it is still clear (inserted via snippet):
$remote_ip = 'smth';
$remote_port = smth;

// Create a TCP socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Connect to the remote server
if (socket_connect($socket, $remote_ip, $remote_port)) {
// Data to send
$message = "Hello, this is a message from PHP!";

// Send the message
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message));

// Close the socket
socket_close($socket);
} else {
echo "Unable to connect to the remote server.";
}

But how to connect data entry (I tried via Contact Form 7), I don't know. It should look something like this,you write the information, click send and it is sent using php


you can send the form to wp-admin/admin-post.php and there use a action to manage data typed by the user. if you need more help, edit your question to show the code you tried.
